# Trying to understand why my test.js fails

Tags: solidity, truffle-test, mocha

I have a function that is not passing my tests in JS but the function works as expected in Remix. Can you help me

contract.sol

```
function test1 () public view returns(bool){
    return(true);
}
function test2 () public returns(bool){
    return(true);
}
```

test.js

```
it("Works", async () => {
  const restaurant = await BiteChain.deployed();
  let test1 = await restaurant.test1({from:owner});
  assert.equal(test1, true, 'should return true...');
});

it("Doesn't work", async () => {
  const restaurant = await BiteChain.deployed();
  let test2 = await restaurant.test2({from:owner});
  assert.equal(test2, true, 'should return true...');
});
```

And then the result is

```
Contract: TestBiteChain
√ Works
1) Doesn't work
...
 1) Contract: TestBiteChain
  Doesn't work:
 AssertionError: should return true...: expected { Object (tx, receipt, ...)
 }  to equal true
 at Context.it (test\BiteChain.test.js:45:12)
 at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: The return-value of a non-constant (non-view and non-pure) function can only be used on-chain (i.e., by other functions in the same contract or in other contracts).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're encountering is that functions which modify the state of code won't directly return state when invoked from Web3. If you were to change `test2`'s type to `view` or `pure`, your tests will pass as expected.

The expected way inspect status of chain-modifiying functions is in one of the following ways:

1. revert, when the function fails
2. don't revert when the function succeeds
3. `emit` events to communicate updates
4. call `view`s afterwards to inspect the modified state

Comment: Ah! That's it. I need to modify state in one function, then use a getter view or pure function to verify the state change. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you accept this answer, it will help others with similar problems find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Bro, `test2` function should look like this:*

```
function test2 () public view returns(bool){
    return(true);
}
```